# PHP PDO lastInsertId() function confusion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am confused with the way lastInsertId() function is written. Say for example I have the following queries with lastInsertId() function.

```
$myinsert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO some_table(something)VALUE(:something");
$myinsert -> bindValue(':something', $something);
$myinsert -> execute();

$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table(something)VALUE(:something");
$insert-> bindValue(':something', $something);
$insert-> execute();
$lastId = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO another_table(something)VALUE(:something");
$stmt -> bindValue(':something', $something);
$stmt -> execute();
```

Now the confusion is that as everyone knows and can see here that in the satement `$lastId = $pdo->lastInsertId();` there is no where mentioned whether to fetch the last inserted ID from `$myinsert` query or `$insert` query or from `$stmt` query. So how does it know where to fetch the ID from? Since, `lastInsertId()` function is placed above the `$stmt` query, it definitely will not fetch last inserted id from `$stmt` query as when the `$lastid` was declared `$stmt` query was not yet executed. But how does it know it has to fetch from `$insert` query and not from `$myinsert` query as in whole statement `$lastId = $pdo->lastInsertId();` there is nothing defined like to fetch from so and so particular query? Please help me understand the way it works.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with PDO under the hood. Maybe someone can explain it better. But, you can see that as a sorta getter from an instance variable inside the PDO instance (`$pdo`). For each `INSERT` call to the database, it responds with a status info. Based on that, it is determined if the `INSERT` is success or not. The id - obtained from the info - is then stored in a variable and is being overwritten each next successful `INSERT` call.

Comment: It will just give you the insert ID from the last insert prior to making the call which generates an auto-increment value.  It could be that each insert will generate one, but it will only be the last one executed prior to this call.

Comment: @NigelRen that's what I wanted to make clear.... I knew this from my experience but just wanted to make clear that what I am thinking is correct.. If this was an answer would have given a +1 ;) thanks buddy ;)

Comment: I've added it as an answer, if you would mark it as the correct one it would be appreciated :)

Comment: @NigelRen accepted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will just give you the insert ID from the last insert prior to making the call which generates an auto-increment value. It could be that each insert will generate one, but it will only be the last one executed prior to this call.

Comment: that's what I wanted to make clear.... I knew this from my experience but just wanted to make clear that what I am thinking is correct..